# how can i test if an item selected from Dropdown menu with Capybara/Poltergeist?

Tags: rspec, capybara, dropdown, poltergeist

So this the page source:

```
<form class="ui form" action="/install" method="post">

                <h4 class="ui dividing header">Database Settings</h4>
                <p>Gogs requires MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite3 or TiDB.</p>
                <div class="inline required field ">
                    <label>Database Type</label>
                    <div class="ui selection database type dropdown">
                        <input type="hidden" id="db_type" name="db_type" value="MySQL">
                        <div class="text">MySQL</div>
                        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                        <div class="menu">

                                <div class="item" data-value="MySQL">MySQL</div>

                                <div class="item" data-value="PostgreSQL">PostgreSQL</div>

                                <div class="item" data-value="SQLite3">SQLite3</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="sql_settings" class="">
                    <div class="inline required field ">
                        <label for="db_host">Host</label>
                        <input id="db_host" name="db_host" value="127.0.0.1:3306">
                    </div>
                    <div class="inline required field ">
                        <label for="db_user">User</label>
                        <input id="db_user" name="db_user" value="root">
                    </div>
                    <div class="inline required field ">
                        <label for="db_passwd">Password</label>
                        <input id="db_passwd" name="db_passwd" type="password" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="inline required field ">
                        <label for="db_name">Database Name</label>
                        <input id="db_name" name="db_name" value="gogs">
                        <span class="help">Please use INNODB engine with utf8_general_ci charset for MySQL.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="pgsql_settings" class="hide">
                    <div class="inline required field">
                        <label>SSL Mode</label>
                        <div class="ui selection database type dropdown">
                            <input type="hidden" name="ssl_mode" value="disable">
                            <div class="default text">disable</div>
                            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                            <div class="menu">
                                <div class="item" data-value="disable">Disable</div>
                                <div class="item" data-value="require">Require</div>
                                <div class="item" data-value="verify-full">Verify Full</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="sqlite_settings" class="hide">
                    <div class="inline required field ">
                        <label for="db_path">Path</label>
                        <input id="db_path" name="db_path" value="data/gogs.db">
                        <span class="help">The file path of SQLite3 or TiDB database. <br>Please use absolute path when you start as service.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And this is my spec file;

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Configure Gogs" do
include Capybara::DSL

context 'Gogs Settings' do
before { visit "http://0.0.0.0:3000" }

it 'fill settings' do
     select 'SQLite3', from: 'db_type' 
    fill_in :db_path, with: '/data/gogs.db'

  within("#sql_settings") do
    fill_in :db_host, with: '127.0.0.1:3306'
    fill_in :db_user, with: 'Tom'
    fill_in :db_passwd, with: '123456'
    fill_in :db_name, with: 'vitakid'
    fill_in :db_name, with: 'vitakid'
  end

  fill_in :app_name, with: 'CODE'
  fill_in :repo_root_path, with: '/data/git/gogs'
  fill_in :run_user, with: 'git'
  fill_in :domain, with: 'localhost'
  fill_in :ssh_port, with: '22'
  fill_in :http_port, with: '3000'
  fill_in :app_url, with: 'http://localhost:3000/'
  fill_in :log_root_path, with: '/app/gogs/log'


  click_button 'Install Gogs'
  save_and_open_page
end
```

end
end
End this is the error I got;

1) Configure Gogs Gogs Settings fill settings
     Failure/Error: select 'SQLite3', from: 'db_type'

```
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find select box "db_type"
 # ./spec/gogs_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Finished in 2.74 seconds (files took 0.76115 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/gogs_spec.rb:9 # Configure Gogs Gogs Settings fill settings

I CANT SEEM TO TO FIND WHAT TO IT GIVES ERROR. PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select 'SQLite3', from: 'db_type'` doesn't work because the db_type select element is hidden on the page, and has been replaced by some divs.  You need to do what a user would have to do which is click on the dropdown icon and then click on the item in the menu, something like

```
db_type_select = find('div.database.type.dropdown')
within(db_type_select) do
  find('i.dropdown').click
  find('.item', text: 'SQLite3').click
end
```